# Composite Predicate of function pointers in C

Tags: c, function-pointers, composite

I am attempting to build a composite predicate using function pointers.
I dont know if this is possible.

My predicates are of the form: `int (*predicate)(int)`
Those work fine.

I want to make a function that takes 2 params of type `int (*predicate)(int)` and returns a function of type  `int (*predicate)(int)`, such that the new function returns the value of a(x) && b(x).

I want to make something that works like this:

```
int ( *composite(int (*a)(int), int (*b)(int)) )(int x) {
    return a(x) && b(x);
}
```

or:

```
int ( *negate(int (*a)(int)) )(int x) {
    return !a(x);
}
```

I understand that my attempts are returning a value, not a function, but if I try to make another function for them to return, I end up with the exact same problem.

If I do:

```
int composed(int (*a)(int), int (*b)(int), int x ) {
    return a(x) && b(x);
}
```

It compiles, but then it is no longer of type `int (*predicate)(int)` so I cannot use it the way that I want to.

How should I go about doing this?

Complete sample code attached for reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int count(const int* xs, unsigned int len, int (*predicate)(int)) {
  int c = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(predicate(xs[i])) c++;
  }
  return c;
}

int isEven(int x) { return x % 2 == 0; }
int isOdd(int x) { return !isEven(x); }
int isPos(int x) { return x > 0; }
int isNeg(int x) { return x < 0; }

// int composed(int (*a)(int), int (*b)(int), int x ) {
//     return a(x) && b(x);
// }
// 
// int ( *composite(int (*a)(int), int (*b)(int)) )(int x) {
//     return &composed(a,b)(x)
// }

int main() {
  int xs[] = {-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5};
  const int len = 11;

  printf("Even: %d\n", count(xs, len, &isEven));
  printf(" Odd: %d\n", count(xs, len, &isOdd));
  printf(" Pos: %d\n", count(xs, len, &isPos));
  printf(" Neg: %d\n", count(xs, len, &isNeg));

  // int (*compositePtr)(int) = composite(&isNeg, &isOdd);
  // printf("Odd & Neg: %d", count(xs, len, compositePtr));

}
```

Comment: your composite is going to suffer because it can't remember the functions passed in

Comment: `such that the new function returns the value of a(x) && b(x).`...then return a third or fourth function pointer, not a _result_.

Comment: your function pointer is a pointer to a function, you can't make functions on the fly as C doesn't support higher order functions.  You could use macro magic to define a new static function as a compose of two other functions but you can't do it dynamically.

Comment: or, another alternative is pass state into your predicate definition so you can store your function composition as a stack of function pointers, though to be robust that would need to dynamically allocated, though it could be capped

Comment: however, I think it would be better to just use plain C and just make a isNegAndOdd

Comment: What about a `typedef int (*int_pred)(int)` to make your code readable?

Comment: Note that insted of `int composed(int (*a)(int), int (*b)(int), int x )` you can write `int composed(int a(int), int b(int), int x)`, they're equivalent.

Comment: This is not possible in C with these specific function signatures.

Comment: Overall this sounds very much like an "XY problem". The question here is: what is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Lundin Function composition is a mathematically well-defined and useful operator so one may want to implement it. No further justification is needed.

Comment: @n.m. A statement such as "if it is math, it is useful" is complete nonsense.

Comment: @Lundin If you think so, you haven't studied enough math. (This is a very convenient unfalsifiable statement).  Besides I have said "well-defined and useful", not "well-defined and therefore useful". I know it is useful from personal experience. Yours may vary.

Comment: @n.m. Rather, if I think so it is because I have studied far too much math and only used 10% or so in real-world applications... Even though I've worked plenty with math-intense applications such as graphics programming and control systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't dynamically create closures or functions in C, so you need to do something else.  The easiest is to use an extra level of indirection.  If you change your predicates to

```
int (**predicate)(void *, int)
```

which you call as `(**predicate)(predicate, x)`, then you can create new dynamic predicates quite easily:

```
typedef int (*predicate_t)(void *, int);

struct compose_fn_data {
    predicate_t  fn, *a, *b;
};

int and_fn(void *data_, int x) {
    struct compose_fn_data *data = data_;
    return (**data->a)(data->a, x) && (**data->b)(data->b, x);
}

int or_fn(void *data_, int x) {
    struct compose_fn_data *data = data_;
    return (**data->a)(data->a, x) || (**data->b)(data->b, x);
}

predicate_t *compose(predicate_t fn, predicate_t *a, predicate_t *b) {
    struct compose_fn_data *rv = malloc(sizeof *rv);
    rv->fn = fn;
    rv->a = a;
    rv->b = b;
    return &rv->fn;
}

predicate_t *and(predicate_t *a, predicate_t *b) { return compose(and_fn, a, b); }
predicate_t *or(predicate_t *a, predicate_t *b) { return compose(or_fn, a, b); }
```

On minor annoyance with this is that for simple functions, you need to define an additional one-word data structure to hold the function pointer, just to indirect through it.  You usually do this with a global next to the function definition:

```
int isEven_fn(void *data, int x) { (void)data; return x % 2 == 0; }
predicate_t isEven = isEven_fn;
int isOdd_fn(void *data, int x) { return !isEven_fn(data, x); }
predicate_t isOdd = isOdd_fn;
int isPos_fn(void *data, int x) { (void)data; return x > 0; }
predicate_t isPos = isPos_fn;
int isNeg_fn(void *data, int x) { (void)data; return x < 0; }
predicate_t isNeg = isNeg_fn;
```

Now you can do things like:

```
printf("Even: %d\n", count(xs, len, &isEven));
printf("Odd & Neg: %d", count(xs, len, and(&isNeg, &isOdd)));
printf("%d", count(xs, len, or(and(&isNeg, &isOdd), &isEven)));
```

though the latter do leak memory.

Comment: What's `compose->fn` inside `compose`? Meant to be `compose_fn`?

Comment: you are throwing away the return of malloc, compose_fn is never going to be passed the right data, how are you going to make this transparent for the user of a predicate_t?

Comment: @dfogni: the address of the first element of the structure is the same as the address of the structure — albeit with a different type.  Thus `return &rv->fn;` returns the same address value as is assigned to `rv` by `malloc()`.

Comment: compose either returns a fixed function pointer or an allocated data struct, you can't have it both ways

Comment: @dfogni: Distinguish between `return rv->fn;` (a fixed function pointer) and `return &rv->fn;` (the address of the first element of an allocated data structure).  Yes, it is weird.  I'm not yet convinced it is actually wrong.

Comment: I did not see the `*`s in the signsture of compose. still no way to convince the caller that calling `*composed(composed, 5)` makes sense

Comment: @dfogni: With that I can agree (I don't understand the signatures/calling sequence yet!).   I've managed to get the code to work, but the predicate functions have the form `int pred_func(void *vp, int x) { assert(vp != 0); return …expression based on x and not vp…; }` and I'm not yet clear what, if any, benefit the `void *` argument provides.  More playing to be done, but not tonight.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: yes, the extra `void *` arg is useless on 'simple' predicates that don't need any closure capture information.  Having to use `(**fn)(fn,`... to call is a little annoying, but not too bad.

Comment: @dfogni: Yes, you can have it "both ways" by returning a pointer to a data structure that contains the fixed function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I once wrote the following code for demonstration purposes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* one int for the implicit parameter n,
 * one int as return type,
 * one int as parameter.
 */
typedef struct int_int_int_closure {
    int (*call)(const struct int_int_int_closure *, int);
    int n;
} int_int_int_closure;

static int
adderfn(const int_int_int_closure *cl, int n) {
    return cl->n + n;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int_int_int_closure a3;

    a3.call = adderfn;
    a3.n = 3;

    printf("%d\n", a3.call(&a3, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

You could generalize this code so that the closure consists of a function pointer, a pointer to its data and the size of the data.

Answer (score 1):

When the syntax for passing function pointers to/from functions was invented, I suspect that lots of unmentionable substances were smoked.

Given a function pointer `int (*)(int)`, a function returning such a function pointer is declared as:

```
int (*func(void))(int);
1          2     3
```

Where 1 = return type of the function pointer, 2 is the parameter list of the function and 3 = the parameter list of the function pointer.

Now if you want to make a function returning one such pointer, and take two such pointers as parameters, it is *trivial*:

```
int (*func(int(*a)(int), int(*b)(int)))(int)
```

No, it isn't trivial... this is madness! If you can actually write and understand code like this, then it means you have simply worked far too much with C for your own good.

What you absolutely should do instead, is to use a `typedef`.

```
typedef int (predicate_t)(int);
...

predicate_t* func (predicate_t* a, predicate_t* b);
```

However, I suspect that you actually just need a function which returns an integer and not a function pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a block-based implementation of your effort to create compositions of predicate functions:

```objectivec
//
//  ViewController.m
//  PredicateFunctionsExercise
//
//  Created by James Alan Bush on 3/12/22.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
@import simd;

typedef int (^boolean_expression)(void);
typedef int (^guarded_boolean_expression)(void);
typedef int (^ const (*guarded_boolean_expression_t))(void);
typedef int (^(^conditional_boolean_expression)(guarded_boolean_expression_t))(void);
typedef int (^ const (^ const (*conditional_boolean_expression_t))(guarded_boolean_expression_t))(void);
typedef int (^predicate)(void);
typedef int (^ const (*predicate_t))(void);

static int c = 0;
static int flag = (1 << 0);
guarded_boolean_expression flag_conditional = ^ int { return flag; };


conditional_boolean_expression isEven = ^ (guarded_boolean_expression_t _Nullable x) { return ^ int { int result = (*x)() % 2 == 0; printf("%d %s (%d)\t", flag, (result) ? "is even"     : "is not even",     result); return result; }; };
conditional_boolean_expression isOdd  = ^ (guarded_boolean_expression_t _Nullable x) { return ^ int { int result = (*x)() % 2 == 1; printf("%d %s (%d)\t", flag, (result) ? "is odd"      : "is not odd",      result); return result; }; };
conditional_boolean_expression isPos  = ^ (guarded_boolean_expression_t _Nullable x) { return ^ int { int result = (*x)() > 0;      printf("%d %s (%d)\t", flag, (result) ? "is positive" : "is not positive", result); return result; }; };
conditional_boolean_expression isNeg  = ^ (guarded_boolean_expression_t _Nullable x) { return ^ int { int result = (*x)() < 0;      printf("%d %s (%d)\t", flag, (result) ? "is negative" : "is not negative", result); return result; }; };

static void (^evaluate_predicate)(predicate_t) = ^ (predicate_t p) {
    printf("\nresult = %d (%d invocations)\n", (*p)(), c);
};

static int (^(^(^g)(__strong conditional_boolean_expression, __strong conditional_boolean_expression, guarded_boolean_expression_t))(int (^__strong)(conditional_boolean_expression_t, conditional_boolean_expression_t, guarded_boolean_expression_t)))(void) =
^ (conditional_boolean_expression boolean_conditional_a, conditional_boolean_expression boolean_conditional_b, guarded_boolean_expression_t guarded_conditional) {
    return ^ (int (^bitwise_operation)(conditional_boolean_expression_t, conditional_boolean_expression_t, guarded_boolean_expression_t)) {
        return ^ (int boolean_expression) {
            return ^ int {
                ++c;
                return boolean_expression;
            };
        }(bitwise_operation((conditional_boolean_expression_t)&boolean_conditional_a, (conditional_boolean_expression_t)&boolean_conditional_b, guarded_conditional));
    };
};


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    // gbe_a is set to a precalculated and stored result
    // Invoking gbe_a() merely returns the results without recalculating it -- perfect for use inside the domain of discourse
    guarded_boolean_expression gbe_a = g(isEven, isOdd, &flag_conditional)(^ int (conditional_boolean_expression_t boolean_conditional_a, conditional_boolean_expression_t boolean_conditional_b, guarded_boolean_expression_t guarded_conditional) {
        return ((*boolean_conditional_a)(guarded_conditional)() & (*guarded_conditional)()) && (*boolean_conditional_b)(guarded_conditional);
    });
    
    guarded_boolean_expression gbe_b = g(isPos, isNeg, &flag_conditional)(^ int (conditional_boolean_expression_t boolean_conditional_a, conditional_boolean_expression_t boolean_conditional_b, guarded_boolean_expression_t guarded_conditional) {
        return ((*boolean_conditional_a)(guarded_conditional)() & (*guarded_conditional)()) && (*boolean_conditional_b)(guarded_conditional);
    });
    
    // Returning a variety of bitwise operations with randomly chosen operands and operators
    // to demonstrate that simd vectors can be used combining multiple bitwise operations into a single operation
    simd_uint2 bit_vector = simd_make_uint2((gbe_a() << 0), (gbe_b() << 0));
    simd_uint2 bit_mask   = simd_make_uint2(flag, flag);
    simd_uint2 results    = simd_make_uint2(bit_vector & bit_mask);
    printf("\n%d & %d == %d\t\t\t", bit_vector[0], bit_mask[0], results[0]);
    printf("%d & %d == %d\n", bit_vector[1], bit_mask[1], results[1]);
    results    = simd_make_uint2(bit_vector | bit_mask);
    printf("%d | %d == %d\t\t\t", bit_vector[0], bit_mask[0], results[0]);
    printf("%d | %d == %d\n", bit_vector[1], bit_mask[1], results[1]);
    results    = simd_make_uint2(bit_vector ^ bit_mask);
    printf("%d ^ %d == %d\t\t\t", bit_vector[0], bit_mask[0], results[0]);
    printf("%d ^ %d == %d\n", bit_vector[1], bit_mask[1], results[1]);
}


@end
```

The console output:

[image]